# How to call a Subclass method from a Superclass method?

Tags: java, java-7

I am trying to make a program which prepares a merit list of students according to their total marks. If total marks of two students are same then individual marks of different subjects are checked.

on line 40 i'm trying to call a subclass method from a superclass method's definition but i'm getting an error.

```
import java.util.*;


class Student{
int[] ph, ch, ma;
int[] total;
int[] total_sort;

Student(){}

// length of array and marks are received via constructor.
Student(int x, int[] p, int[] c, int[] m){

    // an array of p,c,m along with 2 arrays of total marks is made.
    total = new int[x];
    total_sort = new int[x];
    ph = new int[x];
    ch = new int[x];
    ma = new int[x];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){ 
        ph[i] = p[i];
        ch[i] = c[i];
        ma[i] = m[i];
        total[i] = (p[i] + c[i] + m[i]);
        total_sort[i] = total[i];
    }

}

// sorts the array accoring to the total marks
void Sort(){

    for(int f = 0; f < total.length; f++){

        if(total[f] > total[f+1])
            total_sort[f] = total[f];

        // checks for higher maths marks.
        else if(total[f] == total[f+1]){
            int m = Stud_new.mSort(f);
            total_sort[f] = total[m];
        }   

    }
}

/* returns the index from original total array so as to identify the         students' name.
 * marks from sorted array are compared with original array to find the   index of marks in originial array .
 * this index is used to find the students' name.
 */
int GetList(int a){


        for(int j = 0; j < total.length; j++){

            if(total[j] == a)
                return j;
        }


    return -1 ;

}
```

}

```
class Stud_new extends Student{

int cSort(int ci){
    if(ch[ci] > ch[ci + 1])
        return ci;

    else if(ch[ci] < ch[ci + 1])
        return (ci + 1);

    //else if(ph[pi] == ph[pi + 1])
        //csort(pi);
}

int pSort(int pi){

    if(ph[pi] > ph[pi + 1])
        return pi;

    else if(ph[pi] < ph[pi + 1])
        return (pi + 1);

    else if(ph[pi] == ph[pi + 1])
        return(cSort(pi));
}

int mSort(int mi){

    if(ma[mi] > ma[mi + 1])
        return mi;

    else if(ma[mi] < ma[mi + 1])
        return (mi + 1);

    // checks higher phy marks
    else if(ma[mi] == ma[mi + 1])
        return(pSort(mi));
}
```

}

```
class Mlist{

public static void main(String args[]){

    // initializes the names and marks.
    String[] name = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
    int[] phy = {80,112,100};
    int[] chem = {100,120,88};
    int[] maths = {40, 68,60};

    Student stud = new Student(name.length, phy, chem, maths);

    System.out.println("Name\tPhysics\tChemistry\tMaths\tName");

    // prints the merit list
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){

        // index of name is received by a function call

        /* STUD.TOTAL_SORT[i] IS STUDENTS' MARKS IN SORTED MANNER.
         * THIS IS PASSED AS AN ARGUMENT TO GETLIST METHOD WHICH USES LINEAR SEARCH
         * TO FIND THE INDEX IN THE ARRAY OF NAMES FOR THE STUDENT WHOSE MARKS IS PASSES
         * THE FUNCTION RETURNS INT WHICH IS THE INDEX FOR NAME[] ARRAY. and others all well.
         * HERE STUD.TOTAL_SORT[I] IS AN ARGUMENT TO THE FUNCTION STUD.GETLIST() WHICH RETURNS AN INT            
         */
          System.out.println(name[stud.GetList(stud.total_sort[i])]+"\t"+phy[stud.GetList(stud.total_sort[i])]+"\t"+chem[stud.GetList(stud.total_sort[i])]+"\t"+maths[stud.GetList(stud.total_sort[i])]+"\t"+stud.total_sort[i]);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: 40th line is `//set nu`

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/VAeCRX4X) @Kent

Comment: I believe your problem is in `Stud_new.mSort(f)`. You are trying to do a static call on a non static method.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a Factory method pattern-esque solution. Please google it for more details, but simply put, you want the `Student` class to be abstract and add the abstract `mSort` method, and then implement the method in the `Stud_new` class. Then you'll have to instantiate the `Stud_new` object.

Hint: you can do something like this:

```
Student stud = new Stud_new(name.length, phy, chem, maths);
```

It's far from perfect solution, but this solution lets you call a method from subclass in superclass, which is precisely what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a subclass method from a super class method is not possible and it's wrong as well.

This is against inheritance rules.

A super class represents a common behavior while sub classes have specific behaviors which are not visible to their super class.